# ng-class Conditional is not working

Tags: css, angularjs, typescript

```
<style>
 .btn.active {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #FE9A2E;
        border-color: #d58512;
    }
.btn.normal  {
        color: #fff;
        background-color:cornflowerblue;
        border-color: #398439;
    }
</style>

<div  class="btn-group" ng-repeat="list in inputarray" >
 <label   ng-model="ngModel" class='btn'  ng-class="{'btn normal':'{{ngModel}}'== '{{list.score}}' && '{{ngModel}}'== '2','btn active':'{{ngModel}}'== '{{list.score}}' && '{{ngModel}}'!= '2' }"  value ="{{list.score}}" btn-radio="{{list.score}}">{{list.name}}</label>
</div>
```

so here if a user Selects Any Radio button based on this the Css is Set 

normal is set if it satisfies 2 conditions

```
'{{ngModel}}'== '{{list.score}}' && '{{ngModel}}'== '2'
```

and  active is Set if it Satisfies 2 conditions

```
'{{ngModel}}'== '{{list.score}}' && '{{ngModel}}'!= '2'
```

and if non of this conditions are met then default class is applied

so the problem i am facing is when i see the first condition is satisfied it is not showing in outout as Expected it still showing active style even though the condition for normal is satisfied

Please any one Help me correcting my code

Comment: remove the curly brackets {{}} in your ng-class statement

Comment: Not Working even after removing {{}} from my code  :(

i was expecting like by default btn class to be applied and when user clicks on any Item then if it's score is not 2 then active should come and if its score is 2 then normal should come

Comment: @jax  Now its working by removing the {{}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `'{{}}'`.

**E.g.**

```
<label class="btn" 
       ng-class="{'btn normal': ngModel == list.score && ngModel == '2', 
                   'btn active': ngModel == list.score && ngModel != '2'}"  
       btn-radio="{{list.score}}">
    {{list.name}}
</label>
```

**Note** that `ng-model` and `value` are not applicable with `label` element so I removed it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not Working even after removing {{}} from my code  :(

i was expecting like by default btn class to be applied and when user clicks on any Item then if it's score is not 2 then active should come and if its score is 2 then normal should come

Comment: Since you put `ng-model` in a `label` element, surely the `ngModel` will not change. Try to consider that `ng-model` is not applicable with `label` element.

Comment: Okay Yah i Tried Again now its working fine Thanks a ton for your Advice :)